# Operatic aria from the end scenes of "Combien tu m'aimes" (2004)

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack, opera

"Combien tu m'aimes" (2004) is full of classical music. I'm particularly interested in exactly what song or music theme is played in second-to-the-last scene in the movie?

**EDIT**: I'm talking about music in the scene that starts at [1 hour and 24 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaMpbcnXH3w&t=5033) into the movie.

In the last scene of the movie, two main characters are sitting each other and talking. In the previous one, main character's partner (Monica Bellucci) is walking through corridor full of main character's office friends, sitting next to main character's female neighbor and sharing a cigarette with her.

I've briefly reviewed [*Soundtracks* section for this movie at IMDB.com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0420555/soundtrack), but it seems that music listed there isn't ordered by apperance in movie itself.

Can some one tell me the name of song / music theme used in this scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a slow played version of Antonio Vivaldi's [*Dixit Dominus, Juravit Dominus*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-71dDT9fx4).

Alternative [link](https://youtu.be/jN8MJAVGNuk?t=597), even faster.

I've found different paces to play it, and in the movie soundtrack they played it really really slow.